# Show on a Cisco 3850 Switch if a new IOS is installed

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios

We have some Cisco 3850 that we never get downtime to do software upgrades (current uptime of switches is over 4 years). Tomorrow there is power works in the room so these switches will lose power so its a good time to get the software upgrades done.

I believe that the software upgrade is already installed on them and they just need to reboot to complete the install but is there a command that will confirm this? The switch currently has 3.7.5 installed and I think 16.9.6 has been installed but the switch hasnt been rebooted for the install to complete.

```
DMZ#show flash:
-#- --length-- ---------date/time--------- path
  2    2097152 Sep 27 2022 10:07:10.0000000000 +00:00 nvram_config
  3  450568480 Mar 03 2021 12:13:45.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.09.06.SPA.bin
  4       1237 Oct 11 2018 13:50:31.0000000000 +00:00 packages.conf
  5       1276 Jan 07 2020 11:02:44.0000000000 +00:00 vlan.dat
  6       4096 Apr 06 2016 01:34:16.0000000000 +00:00 mnt
  7       4096 Apr 06 2016 01:34:16.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images
  8       4096 Apr 06 2016 01:34:18.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak
  9         40 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap1g2.md5
 10   11612160 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap1g2
 11         40 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap3g1.md5
 12   10485760 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap3g1
 13         40 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap3g2.md5
 14   13783040 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/ap3g2
 15         40 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/c1140.md5
 16   10321920 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/c1140
 17         11 Oct 30 2014 20:24:04.0000000000 +00:00 mnt/images/ap.bak/version.info
 18       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:42:10.0000000000 +00:00 dc_profile_dir
 19     185274 Oct 12 2018 02:42:10.0000000000 +00:00 dc_profile_dir/dc_default_profiles.txt
 20     188811 Oct 12 2018 02:42:10.0000000000 +00:00 dc_profile_dir/dc_default_profiles.txt.bkp
 21   82000420 Oct 11 2018 13:50:26.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-base.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
 22    5663420 Oct 11 2018 13:50:26.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-drivers.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
 23   36965384 Oct 11 2018 13:50:26.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-infra.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
 24   46449984 Oct 11 2018 13:50:26.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-iosd-universalk9.SPA.152-3.E5.pkg
 25   28959628 Oct 11 2018 13:50:27.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-platform.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
 26  128574272 Oct 11 2018 13:50:27.0000000000 +00:00 cat3k_caa-wcm.SPA.10.3.150.0.pkg
 27       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:41:28.0000000000 +00:00 virtual-instance
 28       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store
 29       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file
 30       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file/f
 31       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file/f/fb
 32        211 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/....d2e.cache
 33       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file_lock
 34       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file_lock/3
 35       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file_lock/3/3b
 36          0 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store....fc46.lock
 37       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file_lock/1
 38       4096 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store/container_file_lock/1/1b
 39          0 Oct 12 2018 02:43:04.0000000000 +00:00 wnweb_store....dd.lock
708083712 bytes available (831492096 bytes used)
```

When I tried a #software clean on the switch it showed a lot of packages for 16.9 which arent visible in the flash drive. When I saw the 16.9 packages I cancelled the software clean.

```
DMZ#software clean
Preparing clean operation ...
[1]: Cleaning up unnecessary package files
[1]: No path specified, will use booted path flash:packages.conf
[1]: Cleaning flash:
[1]: Preparing packages list to delete ...
     In use files, will not delete:
       cat3k_caa-base.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
       cat3k_caa-drivers.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
       cat3k_caa-infra.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
       cat3k_caa-iosd-universalk9.SPA.152-3.E5.pkg
       cat3k_caa-platform.SPA.03.07.05E.pkg
       cat3k_caa-wcm.SPA.10.3.150.0.pkg
       packages.conf
[1]: Files that will be deleted:
    cat3k_caa-guestshell.16.09.06.SPA.pkg
    cat3k_caa-rpbase.16.09.06.SPA.pkg
    cat3k_caa-rpcore.16.09.06.SPA.pkg
    cat3k_caa-srdriver.16.09.06.SPA.pkg
    cat3k_caa-universalk9.16.09.06.SPA.bin
    cat3k_caa-webui.16.09.06.SPA.pkg

[1]: Do you want to proceed with the deletion? [yes/no]: no
[1]: Clean up aborted by user
```

Is there a command to see if 16.9 is installed and will complete install on a reboot? I am aware that there is a 16.12 ios for the 3850, is it too late to rollback the 16.9 and install 16.12 instead?

Comment: This should be your last update on those switches because the software support for them ended over a year ago.. It really is time to look into replacements. Cisco has long lead times that are up to a year on some devices right now.

Comment: What does to boot statement say in the configuration? You can set the boot statement to boot from a particular image.

Comment: Yes, they're EOL, but if they're working for you, there's no reason to throw them out.

Comment: There is a refresh project underway so the aging switch issue will be resolved but probably not for at least a year. I have a feeling this was a small bug, when I did `#dir flash:` the 16.9 pkg's did then show in the list and the date/time for the files was the time that I had attempted and aborted the `software clean`. The files now also show with `#show flash:`. Odd.

Comment: The switch rebooted and came back with 3.7. I have done a software clean to remove the 16.9 packages but I would want to reboot the switch again before attempting an install again. I may not get a downtime again before it is swapped out so it may have to stick with 3.7